# Regex with negative Lookahead with special grouping

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to construct a regex pattern, that matches only if another pattern does not exist before...

I need to match `§+\s?(\d+)`
It is important that the group `(\d+)` is the first group in the result set (it is what I need to extract from the input and it would be ways more easier if it is the first group)

What must not be present anywhere before that match is `\d+ [A-Z]{2} [A-Z]{3}`

What I have so far is

```
^.*(?!\d+ [A-Z]{2} [A-Z]{3}).*§+\s?(\d+).*$
```

First it is not working and second I wonder if the negative Lookeahead is present as a group if it matches, because then I need another solution as mentioned above.

Valid examples

```
Whatever §§ 123 might contain after 1234 AB CDE
Whatever §1 the big brown fox
```

Invalid example

```
must not contain before 1234 AB CDE §§ 123
```

Hopefully this is not a big deal.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Does your rule need to make sure that the `\d+ [A-Z]{2} [A-Z]{3}` is not *just before* what you want to match (`§+\s?(\d+)`)? Or should the regex reject *anywhere before* for example `1234 AB CDE some text §§ 123`

Comment: Coding in .NET? Use `(?<!\d+\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}\s+)§+\s?(\d+)`. Your group will have ID 1.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Degant asked, what I forgot to tell. It should reject if 1234 AB CDE is anywhere before... Therefore Wiktors Solutions doesn't fulfill this requirement. I modified it to make that work as well `(?<!\d+\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}\s+.*)§+\s?(\d+)`. Thanks again you too and have a nice weekend! Oh and yes, it's VB.NET.... How did you know Wiktor?

Comment: @ReneKuehne: Next time you provide feedback, please answer each user individually using the `@`+`username` to have the user notified of the feedback. I posted an answer, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, in .NET regex, you may use an *infinite-width* negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\d+\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}\s.*)§+\s?(\d+)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cd%2b%5cs%2b%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%5cs%2b%5bA-Z%5d%7b3%7d%5cs.*%29%c2%a7%2b%5cs%3f%28%5cd%2b%29&i=Whatever+%c2%a7%c2%a7+123+might+contain+after+1234+AB+CDE%0d%0amust+not+contain+before+1234+AB+CDE+%c2%a7%c2%a7+123%0d%0aWhatever+%c2%a71+the+big+brown+fox)

The `(?<!\d+\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}\s.*)` construct is a negative lookbehind failing a match if there is:

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `[A-Z]{2}`  - 2 uppercase ASCII letters
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `[A-Z]{3}` - 3  uppercase ASCII letters
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as many as possible

... before the

- `§+` - 1+ `§` symbols
- `\s?` - 1 or 0 (optional) whitespace
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.